# Update on duplicate key making a new row (MYSQL-PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to do a simple SQL statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO imeiTable (imei, id)
VALUES ('imei','ID')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='ID'
```

Which works perfectly as intended (Where IMEI is the primary key, and IMEI and ID are numbers).

However, when I try to do this statement via PHP, I get a strange result. When it detects a duplicate, it creates a new row with no imei at all, and just the ID. If its not there, it adds as normal.

This is me trying to do it as a php statement:

```
$q = sprintf("INSERT INTO imeiTable (imei, id) VALUES ('%s','%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='%s'",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection,$imei),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection,$id),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection,$id)
);
```

Can anyone understand why there is different results between my php and posting it directly into phpmyadmin?

All my other database functions work as intended, so its not what I do with q afterwords, the relevant code I believe has been posted.